# Why can't this script execute the other script

Tags: linux, bash, debian

This script looks for all users that have the string RECHERCHE inside them. I tried running it in sudo and it worked, but then stopped at line 8 (permission denied). Even when removing the sudo from the script, this issue still happens.

```
#!/bin/bash
#challenge : user search and permission rewriting
echo -n "Enter string to search : "
read RECHERCHE
echo $(cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f5 | grep -i "$RECHERCHE" | sed s/,//g)
echo "Changing permissions"
export RECHERCHE
sudo ./challenge2 $(/etc/passwd) &
```

The second script then changes permissions of each file belonging to each user that RECHERCHE found, in the background. If you could help me figure out what this isn't doing right, it would be of great service. I

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do

        if [-z  "$(grep "/home" | cut -d: -f5 | grep -i "$RECHERCHE")" ]
              then
        user=$(cut -f: -f1)
        file=$(find / -user $(user))
        if [$(stat -c %a file) >= 700]
                then
        chmod 700 file 2>> /home/$(user)/challenge.log
        fi
        if [$(stat -c %a file) < 600]
                then
        chmod 600 file 2>> /home/$(user)/challenge.log
        fi
        umask 177 2>> /home/$(user)/challenge.log
        fi
done
```

I have to idea what I'm doing.

Comment: `/etc/passwd` is no command. Remove `$(` and `)`. Use http://www.shellcheck.net/ for your second script.

Comment: You are missing spaces around `[` and `]` in that second snippet.

Comment: `echo $(...)` is generally not useful, you can do without the `echo` and wrapping `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

the `$(`...`)` syntax means *command substitution*, that is: it will be replaced by the output of the command within the paranthesis.

since `/etc/passwd` is no command but just a text-file, you cannot *execute* it.

so if you want to pass the contents of `/etc/passwd` to your script, you would just call it:

```
./challenge2 < /etc/passwd
```

or, if you need special permissions to read the file, something like

```
sudo cat /etc/passwd | ./challenge2
```

also in your `challenge2` script, you are using `$(user)` which is wrong as you really only want to expand the `user` variable: use *curly braces* for this, like `${user}`

## /etc/passwd?

not what you were asking, but you probably should not read `/etc/passwd` directly anyhow.
if you want to get a list of users, use the following *command*:

```
$ getent passwd
```

this will probably give you more users than those stored in `/etc/passwd`, as your system might use other PAM backends (ldap,...)